# iOS UITests - What purpose XCUIElements identifier serves

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xcode-ui-testing

While woking on iOS UITests, I found [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement) has a property, [identifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielementattributes/1500981-identifier), which was confronted from [XCUIElementAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielementattributes). When I debug, I found this is a real-only property and always contains empty string. Can anyone explain what purpose this property serves? I am unable to get any distinguishing property between two [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement)

I cannot change the identifier, its immutable.

[image]

Comment: You can set each element or component identifier just like tag.

Comment: Its immutable property, please see updated post, though it was mentioned before. @agent_stack

Comment: \This identifier can not be set from here. Here it has only `readonly`, you need to set this from storyboard attribute elements

Comment: do u know which property can be used to distinguish two xcuielement, on runtime?

Comment: i want something which can be used like TAG, but writable on uitest runtime. @agent_stack

Comment: Bro its identifier. It is unique that you have to use. Initially you have to give identifier either  from the storyboard or by the code. Build your project and run your UI test. During run time when you click you can check elements from identifier which element you have. For more info which elements you have?

Comment: I understood identifiers need to be set from app side. I want something manuputable on uitest runtime. If want to work on every xcuielements in uitest, i don't thing its good idea to set identifier for every item from app side. Whats ur suggestion?

Comment: What actually you wanted to do in your UITest can you explain me first and second thing which components you have pls mention.

Comment: I want to get all elements and fire a tap() event when applicable which may switch the screen. From new screen i want to get all visible elements and traverse deep and deep. But for that i need to know which elements of a screen have already been traversed. For example a visited array like DFS traverse. So i have to get a property using which i can check that this element is already traversed/tapped or not. If u still don't get the point let me clarify more.

Comment: That is not what the UI testing framework's intended purpose is for. Really, you need to know which button is going to take you to which part of your app with a state machine construct.

Comment: I know philosophy of ui test is not to explore existing screens rather to test desired screen exists or not. I was just looking for a hack if there is any. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `identifier` property of an XCUIElement is the same as the accessibility identifier of the UIView it represents.

```
// app code
let someButton: UIButton!
someButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "myIdentifer"

// test code
let button = XCUIApplication().buttons["myIdentifier"] // get XCUIElement for the button
print(button.identifier) // => "myIdentifier"
```

If the `identifier` is empty, this is because the `accessibilityIdentifier` property has not been set on the view.

Comment: Is it possible to associate something like tag with xcuielement on test runtime? Or any alternative?